# Removing Container(ScrollPane) border in AWT

Tags: java, swing, awt

I was looking for a solution to remove default border in AWT ScrollPane.

In JScrollPane its rather simple..

> paneScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

or

> paneScrollPane.setBorder(null);

Just wanted to know can we achieve the same effect in case of ScrollPane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably is not possible. One of the main drawbacks of `AWT` was that you can't actually draw over or customize the view of your `AWT` component.

The only recommendation I might make would be that you could try creating Canvases around your ScrollPanel that draw over the border.

Comment: Customize the Canvas would be same hard work as for ScrollPane btw +1

Answer (score 2):

You could use this method:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
scrollPane.setViewportBorder(null);
```

I got this information from class javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthScrollPaneUI:

```
protected void paint(SynthContext context, Graphics g) {
    Border vpBorder = scrollpane.getViewportBorder();
    if (vpBorder != null) {
        Rectangle r = scrollpane.getViewportBorderBounds();
        vpBorder.paintBorder(scrollpane, g, r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that not possible because `AWT` implements `Look and Feel` and is strongly based on methods that came from Native OS (`Themes`), [Border](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/border/package-summary.html) are implemented just for `Swing JComponents`,

Comment: so is there any other way to remove default border that appear on ScrollPane ? Thanks ..

Comment: as I know that there isn't proper way, maybe there exist dirty hack how to extract the Borders and change the Color, you have to try what Components returns the ScrollPane, but I still don't know any reason use pre-historical Components that died on last Centaury